# Mouse wheel event fires continuously and won't stop on Firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, mouseevent

Basically I'm trying to implement a simple zoom in/out on mouse wheel in Flex 4.5.

The scene is a series of nested mx:Canvas (I'm forced to work with MX rather than Spark). One of the nested Canvases has a mouseWheel="..." event assignment.

Now to the problem: on Firefox, wmode=window (Chrome works fine), for reasons unknown, the MouseEvent is fired continuously until the cursor is moved out of the Canvas handling the wheel event.

What has been tried:

- wmode transparent;
- event.stopPropagation();
- event.stopImmediatePropagation();
- event.preventDefault();
- Moving the event handling higher / lower in the hierarchy;
- Removing the listener in the handler and re-assigning it again on timeout;
- various combinations of the above;

Nothing seems to work.

Ideas?

**UPD:** Seems to be happening only after the element has been resized at least once.

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be no reasonable (or logical) solution to this, there is an ugly workaround:

- In the wheel handler, add `handlerObject.mouseEnabled = false;`
- Set a timeout for 1-10 ms to reset `mouseEnabled` to `true`.

Seems to be "resetting" the wheel event.